# Is there a better alternative to Console.ReadKey()?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

Most programming books will tell you to use Console.ReadKey() to pause the console, but is there a better alternative?

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with ReadKey()?

Comment: There could be some overhead.

Comment: Tell us your concerns.  I think you're worrying over nothing.

Comment: No worrying. Just wondering if there's a function or whatever that's specifically used to pause the console.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't actually told us what you wish to achieve.

If you wish to **stop the output until the user chooses to continue**, then you're not really going to get much better than just waiting for a key to be pressed using `Console.ReadKey`.

If you just want to **pause the output for a certain amount of time**, you can use the `Thread.Sleep` method, which doesn't require any human intervention.

Comment: Actually, was just waiting for a key to be pressed. Thanks, this answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

How about Console.ReadLine() :)

Comment: Not an improvement

Answer (score -2):

```
system("pause");
```

does the same thing